# Realtime Routing Direction with MKMap

Tags: ios, dictionary, routes

I have made some routing app using MKMap in the iOS.

My code is as below:

```
...

MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
....
```

I can get MKRoute object array from response.

But i found there is no api for callback if the iOS device reach next step.

I need show the next step automatically if the driver reach first step.

(I tried to use CLLocationManager for distance filter, but i think it is not good performance for iOS device)

Is there any good way to get notification i reached the any MKRoute nearby?